# Error in program for modified bubble sort

Tags: c++, string, sorting

Codeforces problem 339A-http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/339/A

I have tried to sort the values stored at even places of the array(starting from 0).I get an error while running the program or program returns a junk value.What is wrong with my solution?

My solution:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char s[101],temp;
    int i,j;

    cin>>s;

    for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i+=2) //Bubble sorting values at even values of i.'+' is stored at odd values of i.
    {
        for(j=0;j<(strlen(s)-i-2);j+=2)
        {
            if(s[j]>s[j+2])
            {
                temp=s[j];
                s[j]=s[j+2];
                s[j+2]=temp;
            }
        }
    }

    cout<<s;
}
```

Comment: Verify the array bounds and consider using `std::string`.

Comment: You are answering the question completely wrong, the + is a delimiter, it doesn't mean that numbers are only one digit, not to mention that the input is `1+1+3+1+3` (example), and your code won't do anything meaningful with it

Comment: @nrathaus The numbers are only 1, 2, 3, so they are one digit, no spaces. The approach seems sound.

Comment: @nrathaus - The numbers are all in the set {1,2,3} so this approach is valid and sensible.

Comment: For this question it might be sound, but I don't think it is teaching you to do stuff in the right way

Comment: There is no need for a `temp`, as you can use the "+" in between as temporary storage :0

Comment: Man are you doing this the hard/slow way.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett-I am a beginner to programming.High school CS curriculum in my country is far outdated.I understand that my solution may seem amateurish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For odd lengths `len` of `s`, the outer loop runs until `i==len-1`.  The inner loop then terminates at `len - len - 1 - 2`.  Since `strlen` returns an unsigned type, this evaluates to a very large unsigned number, causing the inner loop to read way beyond the end of `s`.  Eventually you'll reach memory you don't have access to read or write, causing the crash.

You can fix this by ending the outer loop sooner

```
int len = strlen(s);
for(i=0;i<len-2;i+=2) {
    for(j=0;j<(len-i-2);j+=2)
```

Comment: You are missing the point: `len` is unsigned, so `len - (len - 1) - 2` will be a large positive value. If it were `-3`, there would not be a problem, the loop would immediately terminate. Try it: `for(j=0; j<static_cast<int>(strlen(s))-i-1; j+=2)` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler should have warned you about the problem (you did switch on all warnings, yes? *always* do that!): Once `i==strlen(s)-1`, the loop for `j` is essentially unbounded, by the magic of arithmetic rules for signed/unsigned values.

```
for(unsigned j=0; j+2+i < strlen(s); j+=2)
```

does not have this problem. (`i` should be `unsigned` as well.)

Or stop the loop for `i` earlier. The problem in your code is still there then, but you won’t run into it. But I believe that is the worse route to take – fix the bug, and *then* optimize by observing `i` doesn’t need to go as far up, because the last character already forms a sorted sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
 for(i=0;i<strlen(s);i+=2)
```

Into this:

```
 for(i=0;i<strlen(s) - 2;i+=2)
```

Otherwise the `s` value be handled beyond its end-point

Comment: Why does that matter?  Won't the next line - `cin>>s;` - initialise `s` up to a nul terminator?

Comment: @simonc, sorry I thought the wrong cause of the exception, fixed

Comment: See @simonc 's explanation, basically because the len reaches (before) strlen(s) - 1, the inner loop did strlen(s) - (strlen(s) - 1) - 2, which meant -1-2 => -3, which is out of bound

Comment: shouldnt it be "-1" ?

Comment: No because he is jumping by "2"

Answer (score 0):

here is my code

```
void bubble(int a[], int n){
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int swaps=0;
        for(int j=0; j<n-i-1; j++){
            if(a[j]>a[j+1]){
                int t=a[j];
                a[j]=a[j+1];
                a[j+1]=t;
                swaps++;
            }
        }
        if(swaps==0)
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail on what this does and how it answers the question